# How can I force Xcode to accept my Developer ID certificate under the General tab?

Tags: xcode, macos, certificate, xcode8, code-signing-certificate

I am developing a new version of my app and I never had to distribute outside the Mac App Store so far. I’ve been using my Mac Developer certificate without any problem.

However, when I tried to switch to my Developer ID certificate by turning off the Xcode automatic managing of certificates and changing the popup menu for the Developer ID certificate, the popup returns to the Mac Developer certificate menu item.

I thought there was a problem with my Developer ID certificate and indeed it seemed that this certificate had lost its private key and this certificate was not listed in My certificates on Keychain Access. To solve this, I exported the Developer ID certificate from another keychain from a backup of another computer and imported it into the keychain that was having this problem. This solved the problem on the keychain and this certificate is now listed on My Certificates list, being properly associated with its private key. However, Xcode still refuses the Developer ID option on this popup menu and still reverts to the Mac Developer option. This is a problem that is preventing me from distributing my app to some users who requested early access to this new version.

Has anyone an idea of how to force Xcode not to revert my choice of signing certificate?

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question and to help others that may find the same problem, when this problem happens, instead of trying to change de code signing certificate on the General tab of the target settings, change it under the **Build Settings** of each target or project and under the **Code Signing Identity** setting. This fixed my problem and now on the General tab the setting is also accepted and the signing occurs as intended.